# Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled

Tags: 18.04

During the start, it shows always the following error message:

> Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is
>   enabled.

Here is the log: 
[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since a couple of days I have the same appearing on screen before the graphics kick in.
It's appearing with some other messages I've not seen earlier:

```
[OK] Created slice user slice of gdm
     Starting user manager for UID 121...
[OK] started session C1 of user gdm
[Failed]  "Here comes the message from the title"
[OK] Started user manager for UID 121
     Starting deamon for power management
[OK] Started deamon for power management
     Stopping user manager for UID 121...
```

A day or two ago all power options under the [Settings] menu were gone.
A reboot of the box brought them back.

As 'zero-coding' is asking: what is wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It seems solved on my machine now.
I've removed all gnome extensions and also all power monitor things like lm-sensors.
From then on the messages are gone in the reports and on screen.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the apport service did it for me on Ubuntu 22.10:

```
sudo systemctl disable apport.service
```